# Run cgi-script on commandline as user www?

Tags: apache-2.2, unix, freebsd, httpd

I'm running FreeBSD 7 and apache-2.2.13.

I am trying to debug a cgi script at http://www.example.org/cgi-bin/printenv . This script is a simple script written in Bourne shell.

I would like to run this script from the unix commandline, as user 'www'. However, the user 'www' does not have a shell (by design). This means I cannot 'su' to user 'www' to execute this script:

```
# su www -c /usr/local/www/apache22/cgi-bin/printenv
This account is currently not available.

# su - www -c /usr/local/www/apache22/cgi-bin/printenv
su: no directory
```

How can I run this script as user 'www'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is fine - that error probably means the shell is currently pointed to `nologin`. Simply change it to a valid shell or use something like `sudo` which is sort of a hack but would work.

```
[root@monkey]# grep monkey /etc/passwd
monkeyman:x:100:101:monkeyman:/home/monkeyman:/sbin/nologin

[root@monkey]# sudo -u monkeyman echo "hi"
hi
[root@monkey]# su monkeyman -c 'echo hi'
This account is currently not available.
```

Comment: This is Linux however I suspect the same behavior.

Comment: The same behavior happens on Linux. However, Linux has a `su --shell=/bin/sh` option to bypass this problem.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid sudo (I was hoping to avoid any system modifications). But it seems this is the only option for me. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I never thought to check if I could set a shell with `su`. Good catch :).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried what is suggested on [Run as different user under FreeBSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285658/run-as-different-user-under-freebsd)?