# "su _www helloworld.php" does nothing

Tags: php, mac-osx, su

In the context of a larger effort, I've run across a particular issue that is baffling me.

On Mac OS X 10.6.7, using the system provided Apache and PHP, I have created a simple `HelloWorld.php` script that, no surprise, just prints `Hello, World!` and nothing else.

Works fine if I execute it as `php helloworld.php`.

However, if I:

```
sudo su
su _www php helloworld.php
```

It emits nothing;  `php` returns pretty much immediately with no signs of execution.

Where have I gone off the rails (and, more importantly, what diagnostic information should I be gathering to help deduce the issue)?

---

No dice.

```
 bash-3.2$ls -alF foo.php
-rw-r--r--  1 _www  _www  37 Apr  4 21:08 foo.php
bash-3.2$ ls -dalF .
drwxr-xr-x  56 _www  _www  1904 Apr  4 21:08 ./
bash-3.2$ whoami
bbum
bash-3.2$ php foo.php
Hello, World!
 bash-3.2$ sudo sh
sh-3.2# php foo.php
Hello, World!
 sh-3.2# su _www php foo.php
sh-3.2#
```

If I copy `foo.php` to my Webserver's documents root, it works.  As it does in my user's docroot;  it executes via the webserver just fine, regardless of location.

---

Even `su _www php -v` fails to spew anything.  Something fishy here.

Derp. The _www user is just busted; no shell. Screws up even the simplest of commands when attempted from the shell.

Comment: Are you able to run this script through the webserver? e.g. `http://www.example.org/helloworld.php` works?

Answer (score 5):

This is very similar to my question ["Run cgi-script on commandline as user www?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/250589/run-cgi-script-on-commandline-as-user-www) (FreeBSD).

Here's the problem: The user '_www' has a shell set to `/usr/bin/false`. According to the manpage "The false utility always exits with a nonzero exit code." `su _www` will always fail, by design.

This is done for security reasons. If anyone were able to successfully run a remote exploit against _www, which the account which is used to run your web applications, then they will encounter a shell which immediately exits. If this shell were left to be something like `/bin/sh`, then the _www user would be able to run many commands on the commandline, and that would be bad for security. So therefore, it is set to `/usr/bin/false` to limit the damage caused by any compromises on your webserver. It is unwise to disable this.

However, setting the _www shell to `/usr/bin/false` also means that the user '_www' is unable to execute commands on the commandline. Even a simple command like `whoami` will fail:

```
# su _www whoami
# echo $?
1
```

The solution is too use `sudo`, not `su`. This simple example shows that I can now execute simple commands, as user '_www':

```
# sudo -u _www id
uid=70(_www) gid=70(_www) groups=70(_www)
```

You will also need to make sure that the user _www is able to read the file. But if you are able to execute this file using Apache webserver, then the permissions are already correct.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing to look at is the permissions on the file.  In general, web files should be owned  by the Apache user.

try chown _www:_www helloworld.php

then try running php as the _www user.